# undefined variable if not exists

Tags: php, laravel

If there donot exists a `$category`, `$category` goes undefined. so how can i pass `$category` if only it exists.

```
  public function receive(Request $request)
        {
            if($request->ajax())
            {
                $id=$request->id;
                if($id)
                {
                    $receive=User::where(['id'=>$id])->first();
                    if($receive->category->name)
                    {
                      $category=$receive->category->name;
                    }

                    echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,  'receive'=>$receive,'category'=>$category)); die;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, we know. Did you have a question about something? Please edit one in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply initialize `$category` within your Method to a null value. So that even when your `conditional logic` fails to `override $category`, we would have a null value to fall back on.....

```
<?php


    public function receive(Request $request) {
        $category   = null;     //<== INITIALIZE THE $category VARIABLE TO NULL.
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if ($id = $request->id) {
                $receive = User::where(['id' => $id])->first();
                if (isset($receive->category->name)) {
                    $category = $receive->category->name;
                }

                die( json_encode([
                    'status'   => TRUE,
                    'receive'  => $receive,
                    'category' => $category
                ]));
            }
        }
    }
```

**ALTERNATIVELY:**

```
<?php

    public function receive(Request $request) {
        // CREATE A NEW ARRAY WITH KEYS CORRESPONDING TO RESPONSE KEY
        // THEN INITIALIZE EACH ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY TO NULL OR FALSE
        $response   = [
            'status'   => false,
            'receive'  => null,
            'category' => null              
        ];
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if ($id = $request->id) {
                $receive = User::where(['id' => $id])->first();
                if (isset($receive->category->name)) {
                    $category = $receive->category->name;
                }
                // OVERRIDE THE VALUES OF THE $response ARRAY.
                // IF $receive OR $category ARE SET, WE USE THEIR VALUES
                // OTHERWISE WE SET THE VALUES TO NULL
                $response['status']     = true;
                $response['receive']    = isset($receive)?$receive:null;
                $response['category']   = isset($category)?$category:null;
            }
        }       
        // SINCE WE HAVE ACCESS TO $response, WE CAN NOW FINALLY
        // JSON_ENCODE IT & DIE-OUT THE RESULT...
        die( json_encode($response) );
    }
```

Comment: So,  i have to first initialize all vatiables to null.  e.g. $receive, $category and all whichever i need to pass?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '';
```